# 3 meals on shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, meal-seudah

I've seen a few questions on this site relating to meals on shabbat, but I believe my question is unique from them.

At the shul I go to for shabbat, they eat one bread meal in Friday night, and one bread meal shabbos afternoon, right before shkia. In the middle, they make kiddish over mezonos delicacies right after musaf.

Can someone explain to me if this is halachically accurate? I thought that one is supposed to eat 3 meals on shabbos, with (at least) the first two consisting of bread. The Rabbi at this shul said that the middle mezonos meal counts as the second meal. What is his halachic basis for this, if any? What are the sources which discuss what the 3 meals of shabbos must consist of?

Comment: Does everyone go home to have their own lunch  meal?

Comment: Some do, but not most. The shul is actually on the same property as a house where the rabbi and his family stay on shabbos, and there they don't have a separate lunch meal.

Comment: So I can't speak for this particular Rabbi. But mezonos is a enough to be called "kvias seuda" in order to make Kiddush, depending on the amount of mezonos was eaten. But the minhag is in many places to have a Kiddush after Davening usually featuring cake crackers kugel and the like.    But everyone goes back home and has a regular meal with lechem mishne two loaves of bread.

Comment: And they have a third meal later also?

Comment: Yes a third meal, called seduas shelishis. Though there is no obligation to have bread by that meal. Mezonos or fruit is enough. Some even forgo it and learn torah at that time instead

Comment: I wonder what they give to eat at your kiddush that your not hungry afterwards and dont need a separate 'lunch meal.

Comment: @cham many shuls have pretty substantial kiddushes featuring cholent, meat, kugel, baked goods, liquor, etc.

Comment: What time is the Kiddush with Mezonos? In other words, what time of day are they finished and making Kiddush. 11 in the morning or 1 in the afternoon?

Answer (score 4):

As you noted in the question, the accepted *halacha* is that one requires bread at the first two meals ([Shulchan Aruch 274:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.274.4?lang=bi)). At the third meal, one needs to eat bread as well; however, there are opinions that one fulfills his obligation with *mezonot* items (or even meat and fish, or possibly even fruit) ([Shulchan Aruch 291:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.291.5?lang=bi)).

Now, the opinion that allows one to follow *kiddush* with *mezonot* in order to fulfill the requirement of *kiddush bemakom se'udah* (that *kiddush* must take place in the context of a 'meal') is that of [Magen Avraham 273:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.273.11?lang=bi).

However, I contend that even Magen Avraham believes that these *mezonot* would **not** count as his second *shabbat* meal. I base this on [Magen Avraham 274:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.274.2?lang=bi) where he discusses someone who has no appetite to eat on Friday night. Magen Avraham writes that such a person should make *kiddush* on Friday night and eat/drink a little to fulfill *kiddush bemakom se'udah*, and then must eat **three** full meals on *shabbat* day.

So, even according to Magen Avraham, eating *mezonot* on Friday night does not count as his first meal. I contend the same is true regarding the second meal, as in your case.

However, it must be noted that some do hold that, *bedi'avad* one would fulfill his second meal with *mezonot*. [Responsa Divrei David 86](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10215&st=&pgnum=497) (R. David Meldola, 18th century) writes that, although one has acted incorrectly in not eating bread at his second meal, he has fulfilled his obligation *bedi'avad*. He therefore rules that if one eats bread at a subsequent meal and forgets to add *retzei* in *birkat hamazon* he does not repeat, as this bread meal is considered the **third** *shabbat* meal, where forgetting *retzei* does not necessitate repetition (see [Shulchan Aruch 188:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.188.8?lang=bi)).

Comment: Great deduction! According to Magan Avraham it would seem that one needs Hamotzi also for SHabbos lunch as a Kal Vachomer from Friday Night meal based on the Principal *Kevod Hayom Adif*

Comment: I was travelling and spent Shabbos with a community that fulfilled the second meal with mezonot. When I retirned I asked my Rav who said that this was satisfactory.

Answer (score -1):

Tosefos to [Pesachim 101a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=101&format=pdf) s.v. טעמו מידי writes

> נראה דהיינו טעימת לחם כדאמרינן בפ"ג דשבועות (דף כב:) כדאמרי אינשי ניטעום מידי ואזלי ואכלי ושתו ואם מועיל מיני תרגימא להשלים ג' סעודות שבת כמו בסוכה היינו דוקא בסעודה שלישית אבל לא בסעודת ערבית ושחרית שהם עיקר כבוד שבת
>
> [For *kiddush b'makom seudah*] they specifically ate bread... and if מיני תרגימא (could be fruit, could be *mezonos* of the 5 species - Tosefos on 107b s.v. מיני תרגימא) and the like work to complete the 3 meals of Shabbos, that is specifically for the third meal, but not the first two, which constitute the primary honor of Shabbos.

The Tur O.C. 273 quotes the Ga'onim:

> ודוקא שאכל לחם או שתה יין אבל אכל פירות לא
>
> Specifically if he ate bread or drank wine, but not fruit.

Although there is an excluded middle in the Geonim (skipping from bread to fruit and leaving *mezonos* unaddressed), *mezonos* would seem to be included as being at least as good as wine.  The Mogen Avrohom 273:11 explicitly makes this point, and writes that *mezonos* is more qualified for *seudas Shabbos* than wine is.

The *Mishneh Berurah* 273:25 cites this Mogen Avrohom.  However, in the Be'ur Halacha there s.v. כתבו הגאונים, he cites from ספר מעשה רב that the Gra held that specifically bread makes a Shabbos *seudah*.

So there is room to go both ways - some opinions hold that *mezonos* (and even wine) is enough to fulfill the *seuda* requirement, and some hold that specifically bread is required.

Comment: It seems from the tosefos cited that fruits /mezonos only fulfill the obligation for the third meal.did I understand this wrong?

Comment: @user2016831 no, you understood correctly.  It's one of the opinions.

Comment: So then that still doesn't account for the  second meal consisting of mezonos only

Comment: @user2016831 Right, according to Tosefos you could not have the second meal consist of only _mezonos_.  That is why I also cited the Mogen Avrohom, which is cited _l'halacha_ by the Mishneh Berurah.  It is a _machlokes_, and I cited both opinions.  The practice of the Rabbi at this shul is in accordance with the Mogen Avrohom.  However, there are other opinions, and perhaps one would best have bread to satisfy all opinions.  As always, consult your Rabbi for practical application.

Comment: @user2016831 Out of curiosity, is there anything you find lacking in this answer?

Comment: Why do you assume the requirements of Seudah regarding Kiddush BeMakom Seudah are the same as the requirements of Seudah regarding 3-Seudot? A priori they need not be the same. The MA actually implies they are different. Look at his Kol VaHomer: if Mezonot is more of a Seudah than wine as regards Seudot Shabbat, certainly it's more of a Seudah than wine as regards Kiddush BeMakom Seudah, so it too should work for the Geonim.

Comment: @DoubleAA Sorry, this post is from over a year ago - I'll have to look back at the sugya to remember why I concluded that.

Comment: You may want to see the new other answer