# Kiddush as the second meal on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, kiddush, meal-seudah

It's common in some synagogues I go to to have a large kiddush with mezonot after Musaf, and then a large meal in the early afternoon. My questions are:

First, does this fulfill the mitzvah of three seudot?

If it doesn't, which seems to be the general opinion in this question: [3 meals on shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59730/3-meals-on-shabbat), what do the sources say one should do?   Kiddush (or not) at the early afternoon meal, then have a third meal after the large meal (hard during the winter)? Or the only way to fix things to bring bread to the kiddush (or having a Kezayit after getting home)?

Comment: Bringing bread to the kiddush is surely the smartest way to deal with this michshol that shuls commonly place before us. You are eating three meals already so just make it count. All other solutions are formalities that aren't generally natural or oneg shabbos and rely on various minority or controversial opinions

Comment: @DoubleAA I've heard of authorities uncomfortable about the 3rd meal being more significant than the 2nd (unless you have a really good kiddush!), but don't know how "halachic" the objection is.

Comment: So bring bread and meat to the shul. The Rambam actually implies the opposite: the third meal (the one that's is unique to shabbat) is the big one. In any event the leniencies you'd be employing otherwise are clearly not worth it for that. First priority is fulfilling the obligation. Then you can worry about how nice the meal is.

Comment: Or just go to shul at 7 if that option exists in your area, eat a nice breakfast with bread at 9, and then eat lunch.

Comment: The question is asking for sources about what to do in the situation described. Those will be hard to come by if they exist at all since the situation described is a distinctly modern phenomenon of no fundamental religious significance. There are lots of sources discussing the rules of kiddush and meals generally if you want to see those.

Comment: @DoubleAA I once saw the shul where there was no "kiddush" per se that week; instead, everyone was invited to a lunch. Everyone heard kiddush; many figured they would just have the fish appetizer and then go home to their regularly-planned lunch. The caterers were zealously guarding the cookies -- the only *shivas haminim* available -- to prevent anyone from taking them too early in the meal ... but IMHO all of this conversation of *michshol* pales in comparison to the liquor, I'm sorry ...

Comment: @Shalom no disagreements there, just that's for another thread

Comment: @DoubleAA let's shmooze it out sometime over a nice bottle of ... seltzer!